# How to create shortcode to show the 2 latest posts

Tags: posts, shortcode

I would like to create a shortcode that displays the last 3 posts to any page....

It should be laid out like this

> Title
>
> Excerpt...Read more

I've added this code in function.php

```
function my_recent_post()
 {
  global $post;

  $html = "";

  $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'posts_per_page' => 2
  ));

  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

       $html .= "<h2>" . get_the_title() . " </h2>";
       $html .= "<p>" . get_the_excerpt() . "</p>";
       $html .= "<a href=\"" . get_permalink() . "\" class=\"button\">Read more</a>";

  endwhile; endif;

  return $html;
 }
 add_shortcode( 'recent', 'my_recent_post' );
```

and it works, except now my homepage shows the 2 posts as desired in a division, but the problem is below the content, ie, below the division with the shortcode, it shows the entire 2nd article (see image).

Any suggestions?

[image: the problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after your `while` loop:

```
        endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

This will ensure that, after your shortcode runs, the *actual* current post is restored, so that any template tags display the right data.

Comment: TheDeadMedic that did the trick, it resolved it for me, thanks and thank you @TBI Infotech

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`strong text    can you pls try this

```
function my_recent_post()
 {
  global $post;

  $html = "";

  $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'posts_per_page' => 2
  ));

  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

  $html.= get_template_part( 'content', 'excerpt' );


  endwhile; endif;

  return $html;
 }
 add_shortcode( 'recent', 'my_recent_post' ); ?>

 **<h1>create a php file content-excerpt.php and place in your theme</h1>

code of that file is**


<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">  

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="entry-excerpt">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    <a href="<?php get_permalink() ?>" class="button">Read more</a>
</article>
```

Comment: How will that work? `get_template_part` will print the content, not return it.

Comment: Add this function in functions.php of your theme . Then call this function on home page. I haven't tested it on my end, please check if it works for you.